# How does the compiler determine the needed stack size for a function with compiler generated temporaries?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, stack, temporaries

Consider following code:

```
class cFoo {
    private:
        int m1;
        char m2;
    public:
        int doSomething1();
        int doSomething2();
        int doSomething3();
}

class cBar {
    private:
        cFoo mFoo;
    public:
        cFoo getFoo(){ return mFoo; }
}

void some_function_in_the_callstack_hierarchy(cBar aBar) {
    int test1 = aBar.getFoo().doSomething1();
    int test2 = aBar.getFoo().doSomething2();
    ...
}
```

In the line where getFoo() is called the compiler will generate a temporary object of cFoo, to be able to call doSomething1().
Does the compiler reuse the stack memory which is used for these temporary objects?
How many stack memory will the call of "some_function_in_the_callstack_hierarchy" reservate? Does it reservate memory for every generated temporary?

My guess was that the compiler only reserve memory for one object of cFoo and will reuse the memory for different calls, but if I add

```
    int test3 = aBar.getFoo().doSomething3();
```

I can see that the needed stack size for "some_function_in_the_callstack_hierarchy" is way more and its not only because of the additional local int variable.

On the other hand if i then replace

```
cFoo getFoo(){ return mFoo; }
```

with a reference (Only for testing purpose, because returning a reference to a private member is not good)

```
const cFoo& getFoo(){ return mFoo; }
```

it needs way less stack memory, than the size of one cFoo.

So for me it seems that the compiler reserves extra stack memory for every generated temporary object in the function. But this would be very inefficient.
Can someone explain this?

Comment: It's pretty much implementation-defined. It is not even guaranteed that objects with automatic storage will be created on the stack in the first place.

Comment: Just in case you did not make sure you compile with something like `-O2` enabled.  Analyzing a non-optimized build is not very useful.

Comment: It is compiled with -O1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) is transforming your source code into some internal representation, and normalizing it.

With [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) compilers (like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) & [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)), you are able to look into that internal representation (at the very least by patching the compiler code or running it in some debugger).

BTW, sometimes, temporary values do not even need any stack space, e.g. because they have been optimized, or because they can sit in registers. And quite often they would reuse some unneeded slot in the current call frame. Also (particularly in C++) a lot of (small) functions are [inlined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) -like your `getFoo` probably is- (so they don't have any call frame themselves). Recent GCC are even *sometimes* able of [tail-call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimizations (essentially, reusing the caller's call frame).

If you compile with GCC (i.e. `g++`) I would suggest to play with [optimization options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) and [developer options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#Developer-Options) (and some others). Perhaps use [also](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html) `-Wstack-usage=48` (or some other value, in bytes per call frame) and/or `-fstack-usage`

First, if you can read assembler code, compile `yourcode.cc` with `g++ -S -fverbose-asm -O yourcode.cc` and look into the emitted `yourcode.s`

<sup>(don't forget to play with optimization flags, so replace `-O` with `-O2` or `-O3` ....)</sup>

Then, if you are more curious about how the compiler is optimizing, try `g++ -O -fdump-tree-all -c yourcode.cc` and you'll get a lot of so called "dump files" which contain a *partial* textual rendering of internal representations relevant to GCC.

If you are even more curious, look into my [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) and notably its [documentation](http://gcc-melt.org/docum.html) page (which contains a *lot* of slides & references).

> So for me it seems that the compiler reserves extra stack memory for every generated temporary object in the function.

Certainly not, in the general case (and of course assuming you enable some optimizations). And even if some space is reserved, it would be very quickly reused.

<sup>BTW: notice that the C++11 standard does not speak of stack. One could imagine some C++ program compiled without using any stack (e.g. a whole program optimization detecting a program without recursion whose stack space and layout could be optimized to avoid any stack. I don't know any such compiler, but I do know that compilers can be quite clever....)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Attempting to analyse *how* a compiler is going to treat a particular piece of code is getting progressively more difficult as optimisation strategies get more aggressive.

All a compiler has to do is implement the C++ standard and compile the code without introducing or cancelling any side-effects (with some exceptions such as return and named return value optimisation).

You can see from your code that, since `cFoo` is not a polymorphic type and has no member data, a compiler could optimise out the creation of an object altogether and call what are essentially therefore `static` functions directly. I'd imagine that even at the time of my writing, some compilers are already doing that. You could always check the output assembly to be sure.

Edit: The OP has now introduced class members. But since these are never initialised and are `private`, the compiler can remove them without thinking too hard about that. This answer therefore still applies.

Comment: I forgot to add some members to cFoo. I've edited the question, so that a instance of cFoo needs memory for the member variables.

Comment: Thanks for invalidating my answer ;-). It still applies since the variables are never initialised.

Comment: That would only be true if they are never used. But they are used in the doSomething function.
Keep in mind that this code is only for the question. I cannot show you my real code, because it belongs to my employer

Answer (score 1):

Life time of a temporary object is up until the *end of the full containing expression*, see the paragraph "12.2 Temporary objects" of the Standard.

It is very unlikely that even with the lowest optimisation settings a compiler will not reuse the space after the end of life of a temporary object.